# Should volatile variables in Java not be visible on second thread?

Tags: java, java-memory-model

I have a small example application with two threads `A` and `B`. Both spend some CPU cycles before each setting a value on one volatile variable (`A` sets the value for `x`, `B` sets the value for `y`), then `B` also prints out the two variables. When this game is repeated a number of times then sometimes the value of `x` is visible in `B` but sometimes not (even if the `x` and `y` are both volatile). Why is that?

```
public class Vol2 {

    public static volatile int x = 0;
    public static volatile int y = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

            x = 0;
            y = 0;


            Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
                doWork();
                x = 5;
            });

            Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
                doWork();
                y = 6;
                System.out.println("x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
            });

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t1.join();
            t2.join();

        }
    }

    public static void doWork() {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            s += i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Threads `t1` and `t2` may execute at the same time. There's no guarantee that `t1` will have assigned `x` before `t2` has assigned `y` and read `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.  Assign the variable and then do some work.  That gives each thread a chance to set the value.  Threads always take a finite amount of time to start and start asynchronously, so events at the beginning can't be predicted.

```
public class Vol2 {

    public static volatile int x = 0;
    public static volatile int y = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

            x = 0;
            y = 0;


            Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
                x = 5;
                doWork();
            });

            Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
                y = 6;
                doWork();
                System.out.println("x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
            });

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t1.join();
            t2.join();

        }
    }

    public static void doWork() {
        int s = 0;
       try {
           Thread.sleep(10);
       } catch (InterruptedException ie){}
    }
}
```

Comment: After the adjustment and a couple of tries (3), i still get x = 0.

Comment: Which could be expected based on my comment in the answer and further demonstrates the unpredictability of threads.  Then the process needs to sleep longer. Change to 200 ms as 10ms wasn't always enough time to wait.  The OS loading programs, the JVM starting up, all contribute to this behavior.

Comment: I've just tested with both 10 and 100ms and after each iteration I do get expected values, x=5, y=6.

Comment: Should this not be completely independent of how long a thread takes because the variables are declared volatile, so taken from RAM in any case?

Comment: Volatile doesn't matter in this case.  Volatile only guarantees that a thread will see it's most recent update.  It does not mean it will wait for it to update before accessing.  But if it is in the midst of updating, it will complete, so it behaves atomically.

Comment: If you change `x` and `y` to `AtomicInteger's` you should see the same behavior as in your first example.

Comment: [or use a proper tool for the job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61181363/1059372)

Answer (score 0):

There are subtle problems with your example. First is that `doWork` might be entirely useless, it does not have any side-effects and `JIT` can eliminate that entirely. Think about it: since that loop is purely a local thing that no one sees, why do it in the first place?

Then, you have somehow a wrong understanding about `Thread::start`, which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60903140/1059372) already explains to you. `t1.start();` schedules a thread to be started, it does not mean that it will finish (or even start) before `t2.start();`.

Then, at least IMHO, you are using the wrong tool for the job. You need [jcstress](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/jcstress), a tool tailored by experts for this kind of things. Here is how your code is going to look like using it:

```
@JCStressTest
@State
@Outcome(id = "0, 0", expect = Expect.FORBIDDEN, desc = "can not happen")
@Outcome(id = "0, 6", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE, desc = "writerY only")
@Outcome(id = "5, 6", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE, desc = "both")
public class TwoThreads {


    volatile int x = 0;
    volatile int y = 0;

    @Actor
    void writerX(II_Result r) {
        x = 5;
    }

    @Actor
    void writerY(II_Result r) {
        y = 6;
        r.r1 = x;
        r.r2 = y;
    }

}
```

How to run that and what it means - is an exercise to you, but the main point is that running this will only give you two possible outcomes:

```
5, 6 --> meaning writerX finished its work before writerY
```

or translated to your code, `t1` before `t2`.

```
0, 6 --> meaning writerY finished its work before writerX
```

and as such that `x = 5` by `writerX` was lost and never recorded. Or, translated to your code, `t2` finished before `t1`.